# Mysql select IN another table row for each returned result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables `section` and `users`. I need to run a simple query to return all sections. However for each section there MAY be a corresponding `id` in a field with multiple ids in the users section. ie `ids` = 2,6,8,10

Here is an example for selecting a specific section by id and its assigned users.

```
Select * from section, users where sectionid = '2' and sectionid IN (`ids`);
```

This would return all the `user.ids` where `2` is within `ids`

My problem is I need to select all of the users assigned to each section in one table?

```
section 
------------------------------------
sectionid,  sectionname,        Description
   2        section2    
   4        section4
   6        section6
   8        section8

User
------------------------------------
userid,    ids(of the section/s),    
  1             4,6
  2             4,8
  3             
  4             4,6,8
```

Desired result:  Display ALL sections whether or not users are assigned to and in one column display the userid/s assignes to each section as below.

```
Result
-------------------
Sectionid,  sectionname,   usersassignedtothissection
    2         section2              null (no one assigned to section2)
    4         section4              1,2,4
    6         section6              1
    8         section8              2,4
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: It's often helpful to give an example including sample table data and your desired result. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you show the 2 tables schema / definition?

Comment: Are u saving ids as comma seperated values then try FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Edited, added schema and desired results from test data. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT 
    section.sectionid, 
    section.sectionname, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(user.userid ORDER BY user.userid) AS 'usersassignedtothissection'
FROM section 
    LEFT JOIN user ON FIND_IN_SET(section.sectionid, user.ids)
GROUP BY section.sectionid, section.sectionname
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9b860/5/0

**Note:** It is not recommended to use a column to store multiple values! You can create a mapping table to map the table `section` to table `user` like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE section_user (
    user_id INT,
    section_id INT
)
```

In this case your query would be the following:

```
SELECT 
    s.sectionid, 
    s.sectionname, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.userid ORDER BY u.userid) AS 'usersassignedtothissection'
FROM section s 
    LEFT JOIN section_user su ON s.sectionid = su.section_id 
    LEFT JOIN user u ON su.user_id = u.userid
GROUP BY s.sectionid, s.sectionname
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/432059/2/0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This query seems to bring back limit results, not ALL section regardless of ids match. I have seperate sectionids for each, the multiple ids are a result of users being assigned to multiple sections.